# Send image print command via ESC/POS using JavaScript to thermal printer on ethernet

Tags: javascript, thermal-printer, escpos

I have a web application and want to send receipt prints via ESC/POS to a thermal printer on the same ethernet network. Currently, printing text works fine, but I cannot make image printing works using GS V 0 command or ESC *.

Does anybody have a sample JavaScript code that shows how to send image prints to the thermal printer?

Comment: These articles may be helpful. [ESC POS command ESC* for printing bit image on printer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44107254/9014308), [Ionic 3: Print image using Bluetooth printer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46904252/9014308), [ESCPOS - npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/escpos)

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't yet, you may want to check out
[receiptline](https://github.com/receiptline/receiptline): "Transform markdown-like text to receipt printer commands."

I think it does more than you're asking, but I've used it to send images to an Epson TM-L30 printer with success.

Check out the [receiptline designer](https://receiptline.github.io/designer/) for a working demo. The receiptline format takes a base64 encoded image and converts it to commands to send to the printer.

I use the receiptline npm package directly, but you may be able to [peek at the source](https://github.com/receiptline/receiptline/blob/master/lib/receiptline.js#L2296) and extract what you need if you want to do it directly without this library.